# Swift - boolean - "if"

Tags: ios, swift

I am a beginner in Swift but I have quite many years of iPhone development experience behind me. This just kills me. I set a bool value (enableStrikeThrough) to be false but somehow the IF statement interprets it wrongly.

Look at the debug screen. I even printed out the value of enableStrikeThrough. And it is false. If I look at the variable list it is false there as well.

How on the earth the code reaches the point where the debugger stopped? (No I did not edit the code after compile so it is really breaking there).

[image]

## EDIT

[image]

Comment: Can you share a project on github showing this behavior? I haven't seen this happen before and I'm intrigued.

Comment: How did you define the `enableStrikeThrough` variable?

Comment: I appreciate your effort. I have not seen anything like this neither. I am very-very confused. The code is too big and it is a close-code project and under NDA so I cannot put it to github. I am sure I miss some very basic stuff.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a playground by any chance?

Comment: @MarcosCrispino I tried two ways: a) var enableStrikeThrough : Bool  = false and b) var enableStrikeThrough = false. Both fails.

Comment: Have you added a println to the if-block to verify that it is really executed? Is the app compiled in Debug or Release mode?

Comment: @MartinR excellent point! Thank you it seems it is not being executed. That is a "relatively" good news. (See the 2nd picture of the updated post). Can you please ellaborate what us going on? Why xcode stops there? Is it a well known bug or something?

Comment: @Teddy: In *Release mode* the code optimizer can *rearrange* code, which means that the blue arrow indicating the "currently executing line" is sometimes just wrong (and breakpoints are not always exactly where you set them).

Comment: @MartinR it is in debug mode. But mixed Swift and Objective-C. Can that be the issue?

Comment: @Teddy: No. – Then I don't know. Have you tried to delete and redefine the breakpoint?

Comment: This could probably be a bug, maybe file an issue so that one from Apple can have a look. But I also think they won't/can't do anything unless you provide a minimal working example (which seems to be hard in this case).

Comment: Seems the issue is virtual so I have to say thanks for all your effort to help me. It was confusing but resolved.